# See letter below: IOS Distribution cert. revoked: What does this mean? I have an app developer developing this APP for me

Tags: ios, development, certificate

**Any input on the following:  I have no idea if these means that we need to simply resubmit our APP, or our they denying our APP for any future development?**

Dear Jane Doe,

You have revoked your certificate, so it is no longer valid.

Certificate: iOS Distribution
Team Name: 
Any provisioning profiles that include this certificate are no longer valid and must be regenerated for future use.

Best regards, 
Apple Developer Program Support

Comment: Did you ask your app developer what it means?

Comment: Please take a look at this related post to see if any of the answers are helpful to you. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/294421/18101